# ERA5 select only the daily images with percipitation bigger than a value per month in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

I use the ERA5 daily image collection where I want to select only the daily images with precipitation bigger than a value per month.

I use the below part of code:

```
//Convert the precipitation from m to mm
var precip = function(image){return image.expression('P * 1000', {P: image.select('total_precipitation')}).float()};

//Apply the function with map
var era2019 = ERA5_daily.filterDate('2019-01-01', '2019-12-01').map(precip);

//then try to filter it
var newas =  era2019.filterMetadata('total_precipitation', 'greater_than', 2);
```

My problem is that I got an EMPTY image collection, but when I visualized the `era2019` image collection, and then with inspect tool I clicked on the image,
I got this graph with values bigger than 4...

[image]

Any help will be useful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a good approach in GEE because **ECMWF/ERA5/DAILY** products have global scope and you cannot "guess" or "suppose" Metadata Image Properties. The 'total_precipitation' is a band name; not a metadata property. So, it is not strange to get an empty collection in your situation. For searching metadata properties in this kind of product you can print first image of this Image Collection:

```
var ERA5_daily = ee.ImageCollection("ECMWF/ERA5/DAILY");

var image = ERA5_daily.filterDate('2019-01-01', '2019-01-02')
  .select('total_precipitation');

image = image.first();

print(image);
```

Result is as follows.

[image]

You can observe there is not any property with such name. However, there is a property named 'year' and in 2019 (not leap year) must have 365 images in **ERA5_daily** Image Collection. So, with following script I can test that.

```
var ERA5_daily = ee.ImageCollection("ECMWF/ERA5/DAILY");

var image = ERA5_daily.filterDate('2019-01-01', '2019-01-02')
  .select('total_precipitation');

image = image.first();

print(image);

var imageVisParam = {"opacity":1,
                     "bands":["total_precipitation"],
                     "max":0.11037624627351761,
                     "gamma":1};

Map.addLayer(image, imageVisParam, 'image');

//Convert the precipitation from m to mm
var precip = function(image){
  return image.select('total_precipitation')
  .multiply(1000);
};

//Apply the function with map
var era2019 = ERA5_daily
  .filterDate('2019-01-01', '2019-12-01')
  .map(precip);

print(era2019);

//then try to filter it
var newas =  ERA5_daily.filterMetadata('year', 'equals', 2019);

print(newas);
```

Now, **newas** Image Collection is not empty (it has 365 images as expected). So, I suggest another approach for searching precipitation values bigger than a specific value. You can use a determined geometry, clip images by this geometry and search values bigger than 2 mm in these clipped images.

[image]